# Staggered gridview empty

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I'm slightly new to this. I am trying to implement [Staggered Gridview](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView), and using it with my adapter causes the activity to display nothing. Here is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    void add(String path) {
        itemList.add(path);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ImageView imageView;
        SQLite db = new SQLite(mContext);
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        int int_id = 0;

        String cat_id = db.getCategoryID(allWishCategory.get(position));
        try {
            int_id = Integer.parseInt(cat_id);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

        }
        List<String> cat_headings = db.getAllItemsMainHeadingsWish();

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_grid_item, null);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        TextView text_cat_heading = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryName);

        Bitmap bm = null;

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.category_main_pic);
        try {
            // Log.d("heading name", ""+cat_headings.get(int_id));
            text_cat_heading.setText(cat_headings.get(position));
            if (itemList.get(position).toString().trim().contains("DCIM")) {
                bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);
            } else if (itemList.get(position).toString().trim().contains("external")) {

                Uri myUri = Uri.parse(itemList.get(position));
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(myUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(cursor.getString(column_index), 220, 220);
            } else {
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image1);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image1);
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setMaxHeight(160);
        imageView.setMaxWidth(160);
        return grid;
    }

    private Bitmap getItemPicBitmap(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap bm = null;
        // ImageView imageView = (ImageView)
        // grid.findViewById(R.id.category_main_pic);
        try {
            if (string.toString().trim().contains("DCIM")) {
                bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(string, 220, 220);
            } else if (string.toString().trim().contains("external")) {

                Uri myUri = Uri.parse(string);
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(myUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(cursor.getString(column_index), 220, 220);
            } else {
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image1);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image1);
        }
        return bm;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return bm;
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}

ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

public void initializeFirstAdapter() {
    SQLite db = new SQLite(this);
    StaggeredGridView gridview = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_main);
    myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
    Log.d("myImageAdapter = ", "set");
    List<String> itemOwnCat = db.getWishCategoryMainPic();
    for (String cn : itemOwnCat) {
        Log.d("CHECK cat_pic = ", "" + cn);
        myImageAdapter.add(cn);
    }
    db.close();

}
```

main xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:columnWidth="60sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10sp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

category_grid_item.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCategoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:text="Category name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_num_items"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/category_main_pic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtCategoryName"
        android:src="@drawable/numbers" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works with a normal GridView, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion or some help?

Comment: So no one has any idea at all?

Comment: sigh, I havent solved this yet

Answer (score 1):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged` straight after `setAdapter`.

```
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I tried it, I must be doing something else wrong. My app just keeps crashing.

Comment: Has it started crashing since added the call to notifyDataSetChanged?

I suspect that prior to adding the call to notifyDataSetChanged, the getView method on your adapter would not have been called. Therefore it may be something that you are doing in the getView method that is causing the crash.

Comment: Looking at your getView method, you are doing various SQLite calls. This is not a good idea as it will block the UI thread and I suspect will be the cause of your crash.

Comment: That code is still from a project long ago. I tried implementing adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on a new test project. I first used a normal grid view to check that the code works, and then I added the staggered grid view code. The image I used was the standard ic_lancher icon. Displayed it five times, but the app crashed with the staggered code.

Comment: Do you have the logcat of the crash?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was really busy. I will re create  the error for you and give the log cat